# Iced coffee script with multiple callbacks

Tags: coffeescript, iced-coffeescript

I'm using Iced coffescript with upshot js when I am refreshing multiple data sources.  The refresh method has TWo call backs one for success and one for error and I want to wait for each call to make either callback.

I can't see how to do this with idced coffescript without making an additional function.  My question is - is there a more elegant way that I can defer to one of multiple callbacks?

This is the code I have currently:

```
refreshMe = (key, value, result) =>
    value.refresh(
    (success)=>
            result success
    ,
    (fail, reason, error)=>
        result undefined, fail
    )
@refresh = () =>                
success={}
fail={}
await
    for key, value of @dataSources
    refreshMe key, value, defer success[key], fail[key]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the only way I have found to do it too.  I'm using it in Backbone and wrap (for example) a model's @save function with an @icedSave:

```
# An IcedCoffeescript friendly version of save
icedSave: (callback) ->
    @save {},
        success: (model, response) -> callback(true, model, response)
        error: (model, response) -> callback(false, model, response)
```

Comment: This is the way I would do it, though it's also possible (but more complicated) to allocate a new Rendezvous, create two deferrals from that Rendezvous, and then wait for only the first to come back.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I use for converting Promises `.then (-> onSuccess), (-> onError)` to errbacks `(err, result) ->`:

```
# You can write like this:
await value.refresh esc defer e, result


# onError - function to be called when promise rejected.
# onSuccess - function to be called when promise is fulfilled.
module.exports = esc = (onError, onSuccess) ->
  util = require 'util'
  return (result) ->
    if util.isError result
      # Always send back an error to first handler.
      onError? result
    else if onSuccess?
      console.log onSuccess, result
      # `await fn esc done, defer result`
      onSuccess? result
    else
      # `await fn esc done`
      onError? null, result
```

You could modify the `esc` function a bit to handle multiple arguments for each callback.

Answer (score 0):

[iced.Rendezvous](https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/blob/iced2/iced.md#icedrendezvous) lib is made explicitly for this case: return at the first of multiple callbacks.  From [the docs](https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/blob/iced2/iced.md#icedrendezvouswait-cb):

> Here is an example that shows off the different inputs and outputs of
>   a Rendezvous. It does two parallel DNS lookups, and reports only when
>   the first returns:
>
> ```
> hosts = [ "okcupid.com", "google.com" ];
> ips = errs = []
> rv = new iced.Rendezvous
> for h,i in hosts
>     dns.resolve hosts[i], rv.id(i).defer errs[i], ips[i]
>
> await rv.wait defer which
> console.log "#{hosts[which]}  -> #{ips[which]}"
> ```