# How to use IcedCoffeeScript in function with two callbacks?

Tags: iced-coffeescript

Let's assume I have such function (in Javascript):

```
function fun(success_cb, error_cb) {
  var result;
  try {
    result = function_that_calculates_result();
    success_cb(result);
  } catch (e) {
    error_cb(e);
  }
}
```

And I use it like:

```
fun(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

How can I rewrite usage of this function in IcedCoffeeScript with `await` and `defer`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an optimal way to do that in iced coffee script, although that post has some interesting suggestions: [Iced coffee script with multiple callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281174/iced-coffee-script-with-multiple-callbacks?rq=1)

I would just stick to vanilla coffee script:

This is how your function would be writtent in coffee-script

```
fun = (success_cb, error_cb) ->
  try
    result = function_that_calculates_result()
    success_cb result
  catch e
    error_cb e
```

and how you would call it in coffee script

```
fun (result) ->
  console.log result
, (error) ->
  console.log error.message
```

---

If you can rewrite the fun function in an "errback" style (err, result) in coffee script, that would be:

```
fun = (callback) ->
  try
    result = function_that_calculates_result()
    callback null, result
  catch e
    callback e
```

you would then use it like that in iced coffeescript

```
await fun defer error, result
if error
  console.log error.message
else
  console.log result
```

Answer (score 0):

From [maxtaco/coffee-script#120](https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/issues/120):

There are two main ways to solve this issue:

1. Build a connector (as suggested by maxtaco):

> ```
> converter = (cb) ->
>   cb_success = (args...) -> cb null, args...
>   cb_error = (err) -> cb err
>   return [cb_error, cb_success]
>
> await getThing thing_id, converter(defer(err,res))...
> console.log err
> console.log res
> ```

2. Use the [iced.Rendezvous](https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/blob/iced2/iced.md#icedrendezvous) lib (code sample from node-awaitajax):

> ```
> settings.success = rv.id('success').defer data, statusText, xhr
> settings.error   = rv.id('error').defer xhr, statusText, error
> xhr = najax settings
>
> await rv.wait defer status
> switch status
>    when 'success' then defersuccess data, statusText, xhr
>    when 'error' then defererror xhr, statusText, error
> ```